# Blur a 2d array of colors in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, smoothing

I have a 1060*629 grid in javascript. I am using svg to create a heatmap, and this piece of code helps me to assign colors to each cell of the grid(hit is an array, which stores number of hits for each cell):

```
var max = d3.max(hit, function(array) {
 return d3.max(array);
});
inner_scale = d3.scale.linear() 
.domain([0, max]).range([0, 1]); 
outer_scale = d3.scale.linear() 
.domain([0, 0.5, 1]) 
.interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb) 
.range(["white", "steelblue", "black"]);
```

After drawing each cell using svg-rectangle, I'd like to smooth the heatmap and fade the rough edges between neighbours. Any ideas?

Comment: You could apply a [Gaussian blur filter](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_fegaussianblur.asp).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. This filter will blur each cell of the grid by itself. I need something that blur each cell and it's neighbours together, so that the darker cell become lighter and the lighter one become darker. In this way all the rough edges will be smoothed together.

Comment: You could apply it to the entire SVG and not just the individual cells.